# Remove class from not orderable columns in DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using html5 data-orderable attribute to set witch columns are not orderable in my table.

So I have this template for table:

```
<table>
    <th data-orderable='false'></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
</table>
```

but when my table is rendered I get **class="sorting_asc"** in  like this:

```
<th data-orderable="false" class="sorting_asc"> ... </th>
```

Ordering is disabled, but I need to prevent appearing of that class.
How can I disable adding that class?

Update:

I tried also with setting `orderable: false` in column definition but I get the same behaviour. Created the fiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/freshbm/128ez26x/23/

Comment: where is your code that renders the table?

Comment: @Unlockedluca: Added jsfiddle

Comment: You can  set this within the code which triggers the table: `orderable: false` - see here https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/21164/disable-sorting-of-one-column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first column is set to be sorted by default.

Try adding `order: [[ 1, "asc" ]],` to default order by second column.

```
$('#exampleTable').DataTable({
    destroy: true,
    bLengthChange: false,
    bInfo: false,
    order: [[1, "asc"]],
    columns: [
        {
           data: null, className: "control center",
           defaultContent: '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/SD7Dz.png">',
           orderable: false
        },
        {data: "vendor", className: 'vendor'},
        {data: "year", className: 'year'},
        {data: "status", className: 'status'}
    ],
    data: newRowData
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I used order: [].